# How I do pre-processing of sentinel1 data using python?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, sentinel1

I have started learning SAR image processing. My project goal is to determine various type of trees using SAR images. For this, C-band data and L-band data are good for analysis.

How can I open or read the sentinel 1 data in google colab using python?